# Linkedin iOS SDK bitcode error version 1.0.7

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api, linkedin-ios-sdk

I used the latest version of **LinkedIn** `iOS SDK 1.0.7`. I used Xcode 9.0

I successfully run my project on iPhone device but I got an error when I archive my project to make IPA file to upload app store.

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/xxxxx/iPhone Developer/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(Pods-dummy.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/xxxxx/iPhone Developer/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk' for architecture arm64

I used the latest version of **LinkedIn** iOS SDK 1.0.7
I used Xcode 9.0

still, I get `bitcode` error when I archive my project to make IPA file to upload app store.

Comment: disable bitcode from settings

Comment: ya you are right I knew I did bitcoin flase then after Working fine but Linkedin Website says that new version 1.0.7 is support bitcode

For that I am confused

Comment: choose adHoc .......

Comment: thanks @Sh_Khan for reply but adHoc selection is not useful to make app live on app store
When I archive my app for adHoc or app store at that time I got bitcode error